# Ads not showing on YouTube embed iframe

Tags: iframe, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, adsense

I have used js to include iframe youtube embed

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="video"></div>
  </body>

  <script>
    // JS
    var tag = document.createElement("script");
    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
      video = new YT.Player("video", {
        height: 360,
        width: 640,
        videoId: "rfYydagxcJI",
        host: "https://www.youtube.com",
        playerVars: {
          fs: 0,
          modestbranding: 1,
          playsinline: 1,
          rel: 0,
        },
      });
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

I also have tried to add

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/goSiidPyiYA" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

But both of these aren't showing any ads from YouTube as it should as per YouTube .

Answer (score 1):

If the embeded site isn't trust worthy Google might not show Ads,
The following information is from Google.

***Requirements for ads on embedded videos***

Ads appear on brand safe sites: YouTube works diligently so that our advertisers' brands appear on sites that reflect our respective core values. Our systems closely evaluate websites and their content against various factors when finding out whether to turn on In-stream ads on YouTube embeds. These factors include a strict set of guidelines on content like adult imagery, violence, inappropriate and hateful language, and sites that promote infringement.

Player details: We require that the video player appear large enough to promote a positive user experience. We recommend a 560x315 pixel or larger player. Also, **videos should be embedded using the standard click-to-play embed and not a scripted play**.

Source: https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/132596?hl=en

Comment: And how do you tell YouTube your site is trustworthy. It seems like the process to turn them on is manual